# Controller name changed when clicking another controller hyperlink

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

This is my hyper-link code, everything is working fine but when I click on the last link I can see my view file but after clicking last link I am getting error message when I click rest of the link.My controller name has changed.My main controller name is tutorials. I want to put another controller hyper-link in my my default layout.

Html->link('Home',array('action'=>'index')); ?>

Html->link('Form',array('action'=>'add')); ?>

Html->link('View',array('action'=>'show')); ?>

Html->link('Ajax',array('action'=>'quick')); ?>

Html->link('Multiple',array('controller'=>'Infos', 'action'=>'multiple')); ?>

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the last link you move to another controller, and when you click again on the rest of the links you are going to the Infos controller quick, show, add... methods, and probably they dont exist.

Change the links to this and all links should work through all your site.

```
Html->link('Home',array('controller' => 'Tutorials', 'action'=>'index')); 
Html->link('Form',array('controller' => 'Tutorials', 'action'=>'add')); 
Html->link('View',array('controller' => 'Tutorials', 'action'=>'show')); 
Html->link('Ajax',array('controller' => 'Tutorials', 'action'=>'quick')); 
Html->link('Multiple',array('controller'=>'Infos', 'action'=>'multiple'));
```

Comment: its working now, thank you skarXa. I more question suppose I have 3 different database and I want to show my all data in a single ctp file how may I do it ? thanks in advance

Comment: If you have different tables, create different models with different database configuration.

class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'alternate';
}

//define alternate in config/database.php

Info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Comment: I am actually new in cakephp, would you give me some tutorial plz ?thanks in advance

Comment: Retrieving you data from CakePHP book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html , a tutorial for basics http://blog.the-nerd.be/2012/08/cakephp-basics-tutorial-part-1/